# Is there Expression Dark theme for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I am just wondering if there is Expression Dark theme for WPF DataGrid?

Or how to adjust it for WPF DataGrid?

Any links?

---

UPDATES:

It's possible replace WPF DataGrid to WPF ListView and Expressaion Dark theme applies good.

```
  <ListView Name="MainTable" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}" Width="140" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Name, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsSuccess}" Width="60" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Success, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Downloaded}" Width="140" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Time, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsDownloading}" Width="100" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=IsDownloading, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding URL}" Width="Auto" Header="URL" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go:

http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/

> A reusable theme library for the WPF DataGrid, so that it can look and handle like the Silverlight DataGrid.
>   Themed after ExpressionLight, ExpressionDark, WhistlerBlue, etc.
>
> Features:
>
> - SelectedCells attached property: data binding selected cells to your MVVM ViewModels.
> - Horizontal scrolling with mouse tilt wheel.
>
> Please see documentation [for usage](http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/documentation).
>
> This project was developed purely in code (XML/XAML and C#), and not in some GUI "designer"...

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I've asked. (+1)

Comment: Link is currently down